# I have this error in roblox studio: ServerScriptService.Main.Base:17: attempt to index nil with 'CurrentHealth'

Tags: lua, roblox-studio

I'm creating a tower defense game and I'm doing a base health system I tried a lot of things and I can't fix this error: ServerScriptService.Main.Base:17: attempt to index nil with 'CurrentHealth' here's my script:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9pOQ.png)x

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB19z.png)